# Занимает ли JVM временное место на диске

Tags: java, jvm, hdd

Может ли JVM во время работы IDE или приложения, запущенного из неё, занимать место на жестком диске, а затем освобождать его? Или эти изменения связаны с чем-то другим? (Разница во время работы и после закрытия была где-то в гигабайт, выделение памяти для JVM стоит на 4Гб).

ОС - Windows 10, ОЗУ - 8Гб

Comment: Может быть, это своп? Или, если в windows, pagefile.sys - файл подкачки

Comment: @carapuz, он используется в случае недостатка ОЗУ же?

Comment: Никто не мешает IDE (написаного на java) или любого другого приложения (написаного на java) открыть файл на диске и что то туда писать. А по завершению работы - удалить.